# Has anyone other than Rashida Tlaib called Israel an Apartheid regime in Congress?

Tags: united-states, congress, israel

In the recent legislation that granted Israel $1 billion of military aid for their Iron Dome defensive system and that passed in Congress, Rashida Tlaib, the US representative for the 13th congressional district for Michigan denounced Israel as an apartheid regime. She was the only one to do so.

In particular, Tlaib said:

> The Israeli government is an apartheid regime - not my words, the
> words of Human Rights Watch and Israel’s own human rights watch
> organisation B’Tselem.

The military aid had originally been part of another bill; but was not passed, hence the separate legislation above.

Over the last few years, two human rights organisations: Human Rights Watch and B'Tselem have called the regime in Israel, an apartheid regime. The latter organisation is based in Israel.

Has anyone, other than Rashida Tlaib, who happens to be Palestinian-American (she was born in Detroit to Palestinian parents), called Israel a apartheid regime in Congress.

Comment: @rick smith: Why did you remove the palestine and militsry tags to this question? The qurstion is about militsry funding and the politics is to do with the Israel-Palestinian conflict?

Comment: @rick smith: I'd also say changing 'not passed' to 'removed' is less informative. So why that change too?

Comment: The question is about statements made. That they were made in some particular context is irrelevant.

Comment: @Rick Smith: You're not making any sense. The question is sbout the Israel-Palestine conflict which is why I added both tags: Israel & Palestine. It is also about military funding, which is why I added the tag: military.  Why did you tag the question with the tag 'rhetoric'. Are you stating my question is merely rhetorical?

Comment: In fact, Section 121 of the H.R.5304, funding for the Iron Dome, was removed, then passed as a separate bill.

Comment: @Rick Smith: Yes, I know that. Nevertheless to say an article from the bill was removed is different to say it was not passed. An article could be removed simply because it was no longer seen as appropriate whilst in this case the article was not passed since a pro-Palestonian faction stood up and refused to be cowed and stopped it from passing. Thos is very different.

Comment: You say that H.R.5304 was "not passed"; but it was never brought to the floor for a vote, hence passed/not passed doesn't apply. H.R.5305 containing the same appropriations, except Iron Dome, was passed. H.R.5323 containing the separate Iron Dome funding was passed. This is consistent with the change I made. As for [tag:rhetoric], it refers to messaging by a politician, for one. Tlaib calling Israel an apartheid state is rhetoric.

Comment: @Rick Smith: I'm not interested in pedantry but the politics of the situation. The point is the provision for extra funding for the Iron Dome bill was tacked onto a bill and this was not allowed to pass by a cohort of progressives. Moreover, my question is not about the minutae of this, but whether or not a member of congress has described Israel as an aparthied regime in congress. Do you know the answer to this?

Comment: *my question is ... whether or not a member of congress has described Israel as an aparthied regime in congress* Which is exactly what my edit did and appropriately tagged.

Comment: @Rick Smith: No, it's not. You corrected mispelling and also removed the term 'not passed' for the term 'removed' which altered the sense of what I wrote. Moreover, you removed the term 'Palestine' from the tags I used, as well as 'military' and added the term 'rhetoric'. My question is not rhetorical, but a straight-forward question: Has the term 'aparthied regime' been used by a member of congress in congress?

Comment: @Ekhad Singh - Reinstate Monica: Can you please stop removing relevant information from my question.

Answer (score 5):

As best I can tell from a brief look, representatives Tlaib and Ocasio-Cortez directly referred to Israel as an apartheid state, representative Bush indirectly referred to it as such, and a number of other representatives used language condemning Israel’s behaviors, from expressing strong support for Palestinians to calling Netanyahu an ethno-nationalist.

The question of whether Israel should be called an apartheid state has long legs; it been a running debate in the media and public opinion for at least a couple of decades now. It isn’t surprising to see it finally entering the halls of Congress.

Comment: President Jimmy Carter wrote a book in 2006 on the conflict, titled, *Peace not Aparthied*. Hence this discussion goes back to at least then. This was written after he was president, so not in Congress.

Comment: I was going to answer the question by referencing Ocasio-Cortez, but I thought she had only made that statement back in May and on Twitter, and the question seemed to be asking about statements made within Congress itself. Did she say something similar in Congress?

Comment: @Obie2.0: I thought the question meant statements by sitting congresspeople, since it's hard these days to separate what is and is not an official statement. But maybe you're right...

Comment: While only the person who asked the question can confirm this, in their comment they said "whether not a member of congress has described Israel as an aparthied regime in congress," which led me to gather that they were talking about the situation that I described.

Comment: @Obie2.0: I'm not sure what point you're trying to drive home by dragging this out, but... Q&A 201: sometimes people get the answer they want; sometimes they get the answer they need. This question could easily be interpreted as an effort to isolate Tlaib as a 'radical', which is unfair in context. I'm a fan of fairness, so context is what I offer. I'm sorry if you dislike it.

Comment: I don't dislike it.